# I want to update turtle based on user input

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
Import turtle

wn=turtle.screen()
i = int(input(“>>>”))

while True:
    turtle.forward(i)
    i = int(input(“>>>”))
    if i == 0 :
        break
```

I expect turtle move consequence of user input and update input, turtle move again based on new input. 
But in my code, the while loop isn’t working.

Comment: Hello! "isn't working" is too generic. When asking a question about your code, you should always explain why it is not working, adding any error traceback you get, or explaining how the code behaves in addition to what you expect. This will help a lot people who are trying to help you! See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the turtle object - `t` instead screen itself!

that is,

```
Import turtle

wn=turtle.screen()
t = turtle.Turtle() 
i = int(input(“>>>”))

while True:
    t.forward(i)
    i = int(input(“>>>”))
    if i == 0 :
        break
```

Comment: This makes no sense.  The turtle screen object doesn't have a `forward()` method.   My guess is something was wrong with the typed in text of the OP's code, not its logic.

Comment: I think you missed the point of my answer to the OP's question as well as my first comment on Thilina lakshan's answer (which your revised answer basically duplicates.)  BTW, did you even try to run this?  (It doesn't start, throwing a `SyntaxError`.)

Answer (score 0):

You need a pen to move, Try this (python3):

```py
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
p = turtle.Pen()
i = int(input(">>>"))
while i != 0:
    p.forward(i)
    i = int(input(">>>"))
```

Note: I recommend you to use two thread one is for turtle screen and pen other one is for get user inputs and move pen.

Comment: Your premise is incorrect, the `turtle.forward(i)` command the OP used is sufficient given `import turtle`.  It moves the *default* turtle forward--you don't have to explicitly instantiate a turtle.  My guess is something was wrong with the typed in text of the OP's code, not its logic.

Comment: Recommending threads to a beginning turtle programmer makes no sense.  The tkinter library underlying turtle doesn't play nice with threads without extra work to route graphics operations to the main thread.  You don't need threads in turtle to do what the OP desires.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, if typed in correctly:

```
import turtle

i = int(input(">>> "))

while True:
    turtle.forward(i)

    i = int(input(">>> "))

    if i == 0:
        break
```

The code in your question has `Import` instead of `import` and the wrong kind of double quotes (Unicode instead of ASCII).